# Swift Error saying `Instance member * cannot be used on type

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm trying to read data from a json file from the bundle and to make this happen I created a `protocol ReadableJSONFile` and it has `fileName` to store the json file name and `readFromJSONFile()` to decode the file

```swift
public protocol ReadableJSONFile {

    /// The name of your json file in the bundle
    var fileName: String { get }

    func readFromJSONFile() -> Self
}
```

And

```swift
public extension ReadableJSONFile where Self: Codable {

    var fileName: String {
        return "\(String(describing: Self.self)).json"
    }

    func readFromJSONFile() -> Self {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(fileName) in app bundle.")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(fileName) in app bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(fileName) from app bundle.")
        }
        return loaded
    }
}
```

I wrote this simple json file and name it `ModelA.json`

```
{
    "color": "yellow",
    "name": "Mike"
}
```

And then created this model to represent the `ModelA.json` file

```swift
struct ModelA: Codable, ReadableJSONFile {

    let color: String
    let name: String
}
```

And inside my view controller I have this lines of code

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let data = ModelA.readFromJSONFile() // Here an error saying "Instance member 'readFromJSONFile' cannot be used on type 'ModelA'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(data.name)
    }

}
```

When I make `fileName` and `readFromJSONFile()` as `static` everything works, but when I do that I can’t override the `fileName` inside `ModelA` as it’s confirmed to `ReadableJSONFile`

Comment: Looks like you need to make both `fileName` and `readFromJSONFile` to be `static`

Comment: But when I do that I can’t override the fileName inside ModelA as it’s confirmed to ReadableJSONFile

Answer (score 0):

you can not access member of class that is not type members to do that you need to create object (instance) of your class like i have created below,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let instance = ModelA()
    let data = instance.readFromJSONFile() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(data.name)
    }

}
```